# PaError not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, namespaces, portaudio

I have been trying for some while to include portaudio to my c++ project, but seem to have some problem with the including, as my project does NOT "know" portaudio namespace, but qt autocomplete the functions names, as if it knew them.

Source directory:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt.user
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── database
    │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   │   ├── database.cpp
    │   │   └── database.h
    │   ├── match
    │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   │   ├── match.cpp
    │   │   └── match.h
    │   ├── record
    │   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   │   ├── record.cpp
    │   │   └── record.h
    │   └── spectogram
    │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │       ├── spectogram.cpp
    │       └── spectogram.h
    └── main.cpp
```

The portaudio tutorial suggest that for building portaudio in a linux environment, one need to copy the files which currently resides in audio/portaudio from the portaudio source files, which apparently should be enough.

```
CMakeLists.txt within record:
MESSAGE( “In reord CMAKELIST” )
MESSAGE(":" <Project_source_dir> )
# Include externalproject {portaudio} if lib/portaudio don't exist.

INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              lib/portaudio
    UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     0
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     sudo make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)

SET(portaudio_lib_dir "${BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs")
SET(portaudio_inc_dir "${SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_library(record STATIC record.cpp record.h)

add_library(portaudio STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(portaudio PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${portaudio_lib_dir}/libportaudio.a")

set_property(TARGET portaudio APPEND PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_dependencies(portaudio project_portaudio)     # Not sure if this is allowed for imported targets though

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(ALSA REQUIRED)

IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
   SET(EXTRA_LIBS rt asound jack)
ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")

#
# this makes sure we have compiler flags that allow class::class() = default (>= C++11)
target_link_libraries(record PUBLIC  ${EXTRA_LIBS} Threads::Threads portaudio)
target_compile_features(record PUBLIC cxx_defaulted_functions)
target_include_directories(record PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${project_portaudio})
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "record.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    record test;
    test.example();

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

record.cpp:

```
#include "record.h"

record::record()
{
    std::cout << "Record Created!" << std::endl;
}

void record::example()
{
    std::cout << "In example!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;
}
```

record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H
#include <iostream>
#include "portaudio.h"

class record
{
public:
    record();
    void example();
};

#endif // RECORD_H
```

I tried including portaudio in to my record class, and see whether it understood portaudio function such as Pa_getversion.. but instead I seem to get error mesages as these:

```
/home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:421: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:422: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:424: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:425: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods_integer'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:426: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:428: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:433: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:434: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_max'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:436: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_period_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:437: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_format'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:438: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_access'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:439: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_dump'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:440: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:442: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:443: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods_max'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:444: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:445: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:446: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size_max'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:447: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size_max'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:448: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:449: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_max'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:450: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_numden'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:452: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_sizeof'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:453: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_malloc'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:454: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_current'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:455: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:456: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:457: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_free'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:458: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:459: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_stop_threshold'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:460: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_get_boundary'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:461: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_threshold'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:462: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:463: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_xfer_align'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:464: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:466: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:467: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_sizeof'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:468: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_malloc'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:469: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_free'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:470: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_device'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:471: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_subdevice'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:472: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_stream'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:473: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_get_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:474: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_get_card'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:476: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_pcm_next_device'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:477: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_pcm_info'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:478: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_open'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:479: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_close'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:480: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_malloc'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:481: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_free'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:482: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:483: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_sizeof'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:484: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_get_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:486: undefined reference to `snd_config'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:487: undefined reference to `snd_config_update'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:488: undefined reference to `snd_config_search'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:489: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_entry'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:490: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_first'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:491: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_end'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:492: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_next'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:493: undefined reference to `snd_config_get_string'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:494: undefined reference to `snd_config_get_id'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:495: undefined reference to `snd_config_update_free_global'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:497: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:498: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_sizeof'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:499: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:500: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_state'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:501: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_trigger_tstamp'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:502: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_delay'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:504: undefined reference to `snd_card_next'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:505: undefined reference to `snd_asoundlib_version'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:506: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:507: undefined reference to `snd_output_stdio_attach'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `GetStreamTime':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1738: undefined reference to `jack_frame_time'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1738: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `UpdateQueue':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1427: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `JackCallback':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1562: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_buffer'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `RealProcess':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1349: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1365: undefined reference to `jack_frame_time'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1367: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1370: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1391: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_buffer'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1402: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_buffer'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `RealStop':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1688: undefined reference to `jack_port_connected'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1690: undefined reference to `jack_port_disconnect'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1696: undefined reference to `jack_port_connected'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1698: undefined reference to `jack_port_disconnect'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `StartStream':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1609: undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1609: undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1609: undefined reference to `jack_connect'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1619: undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1619: undefined reference to `jack_port_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1619: undefined reference to `jack_connect'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `CleanUpStream':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:983: undefined reference to `jack_port_unregister'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:988: undefined reference to `jack_port_unregister'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `OpenStream':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1080: undefined reference to `jack_port_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1081: undefined reference to `jack_client_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1087: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1181: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1214: undefined reference to `jack_port_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1215: undefined reference to `jack_port_register'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1224: undefined reference to `jack_port_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1225: undefined reference to `jack_port_register'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1241: undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1245: undefined reference to `jack_port_by_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1265: undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1269: undefined reference to `jack_port_by_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1301: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1302: undefined reference to `jack_get_buffer_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1305: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:733: undefined reference to `jack_client_open'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `BuildDeviceList':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:491: undefined reference to `jack_client_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:492: undefined reference to `jack_client_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:499: undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:517: undefined reference to `jack_client_name_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:558: undefined reference to `jack_get_sample_rate'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:589: undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:596: undefined reference to `jack_port_by_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:598: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:610: undefined reference to `jack_get_ports'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:617: undefined reference to `jack_port_by_name'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:619: undefined reference to `jack_port_get_latency'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `PaJack_Initialize':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:781: undefined reference to `jack_on_shutdown'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:782: undefined reference to `jack_set_error_function'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:783: undefined reference to `jack_get_buffer_size'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:785: undefined reference to `jack_set_sample_rate_callback'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:786: undefined reference to `jack_set_xrun_callback'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:800: undefined reference to `jack_client_close'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:787: undefined reference to `jack_set_process_callback'
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:788: undefined reference to `jack_activate'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `PaJack_SetClientName':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1750: undefined reference to `jack_client_name_size'
    include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio-build/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_jack.o): In function `PaJack_GetClientName':
    /home/lambda/soundcloud/build/src/include/record/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:1765: undefined reference to `jack_get_client_name'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [src/cmakeDemo] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cmakeDemo.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: According to [this documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a4949e4a8ef9f9dbe8cbee414ce69841d) we have `typedef int PaError`. So the compiler is right, it is not a class or a namespace and cannot be used that way.

Comment: So I should be able to print it without any namespace?.. doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: Or something like Pa_GetVersion() should be printable without any namespace...

Comment: Well yes, if you look at the [source code](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h_source.html) there is no namespace anywhere!? Also `PaError::` as namespace is pretty weird, if there would be a namespace then more like `Pa::GetVersion()`

Comment: The title describes a compile error, not a link error.

Comment: I guess linking could cause confusing... will change that..

Comment: If `PaError` is an `int` and `Pa_GetVersion()` is a function, `PaError::Pa_GetVersion()` just doesn't mean anything. What did you intend it to do?

Comment: I tried printing `Pa_GetVersion()` without any namespace, which didn't output anything..

Comment: despite what the example posted above is showing.. I tried with, and without..

Comment: What do you mean "didn't output anything"? It's an `int` so does it output `0` or really nothing that would be very very weird? Have you tried with `Pa_GetVersionInfo()` if that works?

Comment: error: undefined reference to `Pa_GetVersion'

Comment: The same occurs with `Pa_GetVersionInfo()`

Comment: Add `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio)` at the end of your `CMakeLists.txt`. The last line of your `example()` member function should be `std::cout << Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;`. With those changes, I could get your example to compile and run.

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator does look into your file system. Thus it finds files which are not in scope of your CMakeLists.txt. And as far as I know this works for autocompletion, too.

Within our CMakeLists.txt there is no line to add the static library to your project. Something like

```
add_library(libaudio NAME libportaudio.a PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/portaudio)
...

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libaudio})
```

seems to be is missing.

Try to build libportaudio as shared lib. Read the build instruction or call `./configure --help` of portaudio to get more details.

Comment: I tried that... I seem to get other linking error when adding portaudio in my target_link_libraries.. 

Issues with undefined reference to function related to ALSA and Jack.

Comment: That has to be solved, too. Did you read the build instructions for portaudio at linux http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html ?
Did you perform `sudo apt-get install libasound-dev`?

Comment: and about shared.. 
it standard.

Comment: Use `libaudioport.so` instead of `libaudioport.a` in your CMakeLists.txt. Your log contains only linker errors, don't it? You can review this by trigger the build from the command line. Run 'make' and check whether the compiler or the linker produces the error.

Comment: Well.. those are undefined references.. I got those after i added portaudio in target_link_libraries..

Comment: what do you mean by "trigger the build"?

Comment: To trigger the build, open an terminal, go to the folder QtCreator builds your application in. Call `cmake .` (Don't miss the point!). Call `make`. Watch the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157932/discussion-between-th-thielemann-and-lamda).

Comment: I guess I can't list all the errors.. I could make the project public... like put it on gihub or something.. and then you could run it..

Answer (score 0):

> which it doesn't seem to like. PaError not a class or namespace ?

Looking at the code documented here:

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h_source.html

Shows:

~snip

```
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   49 extern "C"
   50 {
   51 #endif /* __cplusplus */
   52 
   58 int Pa_GetVersion( void );
   59 
   67 const char* Pa_GetVersionText( void );
   68 
   81 #define paMakeVersionNumber(major, minor, subminor) \
   82     (((major)&0xFF)<<16 | ((minor)&0xFF)<<8 | ((subminor)&0xFF))
   83 
   84 
   90 typedef struct PaVersionInfo {
   91     int versionMajor;
   92     int versionMinor;
   93     int versionSubMinor;
   99     const char *versionControlRevision;
  101     const char *versionText;
  102 } PaVersionInfo;
  103     
  114 const PaVersionInfo* Pa_GetVersionInfo();
  115 
  116 
  121 typedef int PaError;  
  ...
```

Based on that, it does not appear to be using any custom C++ namespace.

PaError is just defined as an int.

So your code:

```
std::cout << PaError::Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;
```

Is essentially trying to treat an int as a class type that contains a method for Pa_GetVersion(). That makes sense about the error you are getting.

From the header file, Pa_GetVersion() appears to be a standard C style exported function, as listed here in portaudio.h:

```
58 int Pa_GetVersion( void );
```

Therefore you should be able to simply call the function as is. So try changing your code to:

```
std::cout << Pa_GetVersion() << std::endl;
```

And it looks like it should return an int.